# no PDB file for ntdll.dll

Tags: visual-c++

Trying to debug dll project I developing. I got message box `Debugging information for 'ntdll.dll' cannot be found or does not match. Cannot find or open the PDB file` while trying to load this dll with host application. How to solve this problem?

After some experiments and setting VS2010 to get symbols from server I have following message while buildind dll:

DEMO.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
DEMO.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
DEMO.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
DEMO.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).

But still have described messagebox while run debug.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files?  If this is the case, maybe some files including ntdll.dll were not downloaded yet.  See here (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) for more info.

Comment: I'm new to Symbol Server things. I'm using default VS2010 professional installation. I'm just wondering why my another machine with visual studio that installed from the same CD not rises those messages.

Comment: I have updated problem description. I have downloaded required PDB files, but still have problem.

Comment: You are forgetting to describe exactly what you did to get to this message box.  In all likelihood you actually got an exception and the debugger is trying to show you what's going on.  Without being able to do so since you don't have the source code for the Windows operating system.  Next likely reason for the exception is that your program is corrupting the heap.  Look in the Output window for diagnostic messages.

Comment: Downloaded symbol packages are not as useful as the Microsoft Symbol Server because Windows Updates often modify ntdll.dll and other system DLLs which means the downloaded PDBs are out of date. Use the symbol server.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options you can have.

1. Download symbol package provided by microsoft. This will download PDB for all system libraries. Extract it to "c:\symbolcache"
2. Set symbol path to SRV*c:\symbolcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols. In this case this will download PDB files and store them into "c:\symbolcache" if not present.

Then you have to set "c:\symbolcache" as your symbol file path into whatever crash dump analysis tool you are using.